# Validate Gmail username using regex

Tags: regex, gmail, pcre

I'm trying validate Gmail username by using their self rule on create account page.

There are the rules:

1. First and last character of username must be an ascii letter (a-z) or number (0-9)
2. Username must be between 6 and 30 characters long
3. Only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9), and periods (.) are allowed
4. Username cannot contain consecutive periods (.)

Expecting results:

```
.carlos.so@gmail.com - invalid
carlos.so.@gmail.com - invalid
carlos..so@gmail.com - invalid
carlos_so@gmail.com - invalid
carlos.so@gmail.com - valid
```

Already tried the pattern above but without success:
`(?!\.)[a-zA-Z_.]{6,30}(?!.*\.)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?=[a-zA-Z0-9.]{5,29}@)[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@gmail\.com$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` Match a single char a-zA-Z0-9
- `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9.]{5,29}@)` Assert 5-29 allowed chars to the right  followed by @
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` Match optional chars a-zA-Z0-9
- `(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat matching `.` and 1+ allowed chars
- `@gmail\.com` Match `@gmail.com`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/jAjOZG/1).

Comment: Works perfectly following all the rules imposed by Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

So a partial answer (I can't leave comments on stack overflow yet), would be

^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9.]{5,29}[A-Za-z0-9]@gmail.com

This will handle all cases except if two or more periods occur consecutively.

Is there a reason why you need it all in a single regex, or could you use two regexes? You weren't clear, but if that is a possibility it might be a good idea.

Comment: Yes, can it would be in two regexes but I prefer all in a single regex only if it was possible.